# matplotlib pyqt4 pandas: multiple checkboxes to select which plots to show

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas, pyqt4

I have the following imports:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('QT4Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
pd.options.display.mpl_style='default'
```

and the following figure:

```
fig, axarr = plt.subplots(3, sharex=True)
```

In subplot 0, I then plot a single column from multiple dataframes. The x axis is a date axis.

```
for month in months:
    alldataframes[month].Column1.plot( axarr[0] )
```

Subplots 1 and 2 are fine, there's no question about them.

There are about 200 months, so subplot 0 contains different 200 'lines'.
I would like to add the ability for the user to select which 'lines' to show to unclutter the resulting subplot.
I could potentially display 200 checkboxes, 1 for each month. Checking 1 box shows/hides the corresponding month from subplot0.
Is there a more convenient interface for this?
If not, how do I do that with pyqt4 or with matplotlib?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can embed the matplotlib figure into a pyqt gui, but it's a little complex, for your case, you can add a qt dock panel to an exist figure. Here is an example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("Qt4Agg") # This program works with Qt only
import pylab as pl
fig, ax1 = pl.subplots()

t = np.linspace(0, 10, 200)
lines = []
for freq in np.linspace(1, 10, 30):
    lines.extend(pl.plot(t, np.sin(2*np.pi*freq*t), label="f={}".format(freq)))

### control panel ###
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PyQt4 import QtCore
from PyQt4.QtCore import Qt

root = fig.canvas.manager.window
panel = QtGui.QWidget()
hbox = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(panel)
list_box = QtGui.QListWidget(parent = panel)
list_box.setSelectionMode(QtGui.QListWidget.MultiSelection)
list_box.setFlow(QtGui.QListView.LeftToRight)
list_box.setWrapping(True)
list_box.setGridSize(QtCore.QSize(150, 20))
for line in lines:
    list_box.addItem(line.get_label())
button_update = QtGui.QPushButton("update", panel)

def on_update(event):
    selected_labels = set([item.text() for item in list_box.selectedItems()])
    for line in lines:
        line.set_visible(line.get_label() in selected_labels)
    fig.canvas.draw()

button_update.clicked.connect(on_update)
hbox.addWidget(list_box)
hbox.addWidget(button_update)
panel.setLayout(hbox)

dock = QtGui.QDockWidget("control", root)
root.addDockWidget(Qt.BottomDockWidgetArea, dock)
dock.setWidget(panel)
######################

fig.show()
```

Here is the gui:

[image]

Comment: I did tried this code with slight modification for PyQt5. The app starts, a window flashes and closes. I can't see anything.

Comment: Maybe I have guessed the missing part: pl.show() at the end. I got some sinewaves with different frequencies that can be turned on/of